# catch asynctask ANR

Tags: android, timeout, android-asynctask

My downloadFile AsyncTask may need quite some time in case of concurrent downloads over 2g networks. I suspect that it is killed off but I am not sure.

My question is: what is the timeout on an asynctask and what function is called when android kills my task? If an exception is thrown, where to catch it?

Comment: I think there isn't something like timeout. But there is something like 'thread pool' so thread in thread pool can be killed. You should read this [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Comment: The real problem of time-consuming AsyncTask is, if the Activity (where AsyncTask is started) is destroyed and you leave AsyncTask keep running, it will become unreachable and cause memory leak, and result variety of Exception as the consequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android shouldn't kill your task. An AsyncTask is just that, Asynchronous, so Android will not throw ANRs for it.

If you want to test for exceptions within the doInBackground, wrap your code in relevent try catch blocks and then throw or handle exceptions if and when they arise.

You can cancel an AsyncTask but you must then check at relavent intervals within your task the `isCancelled` flag.

Once you have cancelled the task, `onPostExecute()` will not be called.

Further reading is of course available here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

ADDITION:
Note, perhaps importantly that Android Ice Cream Sandwich, and perhaps Honeycomb shifted away from Thread pool execution as the default and use instead a serialised approach. If you find on ICS that your Tasks appear never to be executed, or executed after a significant wait, you should execute using `executeOnExecutor()` and pass it the `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` parameter. More information is available at the above link.